# node.js Array.length issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

array.length is returning 0 always....
Its returning 0 even some item added into the array...

```
 function validate () { 

  error = new Array();

  if(req.body.category_id==""){ 
    error['category_id'] = "Please select category";
  }

  if(req.body.text==""){ 
    error['text'] = "Enter the word";
  }

  if(!(req.body.email!="" && req.body.email.test(/@/))){ 
    error['email'] = "Invalid email id";
  }

  if((req.session.number1+req.session.number2)!=req.body.captcha){ 
    error['captcha'] = "Captcha verification failed";
  }  

 console.log(error.length);
 console.log(error['category_id']);

  if(error.length){ 
    return false;   
  }else{ 
    return true;
  }
}

result of the console.log
//0
//Please select category
```

Comment: this is not solution but can you try `console.log(error.length);` inside first IF condition. we may get more details after looking at its result.

Comment: Seems to me that you're using your "Array" as a map/object.

Comment: @Pranav its going else section only....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not have associative arrays, make it object like:

```
//function to get size of object
Object.prototype.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
var error = {}; //object
if(req.body.category_id==""){ 
    error['category_id'] = "Please select category";
}
...
//rest of your code
if( Object.size(error) ){ //check if we have error
    return false;   
}else{ 
    return true;
}

//check the size of object
console.log(  Object.size(error) );
console.log(error['category_id']);
```

Comment: `return Object.keys(obj).length`?

Comment: Never, ever modify objects you don't own. This goes double for built-in objects like Array or Object. Haven't we learned anything from prototype.js?

Comment: -1 Object.keys(error).length would be far superior: it does the same thing using a built in function and without modifying Object.prototype.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.length` only counts values whose key is *numeric*.  You are using *strings* as the keys, so your length is always 0.  Though legal, (since Arrays are Objects) this is confusing and isn't a good fit for an array.

As @Sudhir suggests, use an "object" or "hash" : the { } notation.  Much clearer.  (Though I disagree with him modifying with the Object.prototype)

Answer (score 0):

```
var error = function(){};
error.prototype.test=[1,2,3];  //1,2,3 only example
console.log(new error().test.length);
```

Use [JavaScript.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/572996#572996)

But objects created with this function will have this property in their prototype chain (as `prototype property` of `error` points to the object that has `test` property defined.